# jQuery animate() fires after a pause on scrolling

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make a simple sticky navbar that is invisible on top of a page and slides down when you scroll the page down. First I used scrollUp() / ScrollDown() but I don't like the way it looks because it animates the height and I want to animate position. It just looks different.
So I decided to use animate() and apply it to margin-top.

HTML:

```
<div>
...lots of blocks and text
</div>
<div class="top_bar">some elements here</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top_bar {
    margin-top: -70px; 
    height:70px; 
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 1000; 
    background:#156373; 
    color: #fff; 
    text-align:center;
}
```

JS:

```
var stickyBar = function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 100) {
        $('.top_bar').animate({
            "margin-top": 0
        },"fast");
        } else {
        $('.top_bar').animate({
            "margin-top": -70
        },"fast");
    }
};
$(window).scroll(function() {  
    stickyBar();  
});
```

The problem is it animates after some pause. I scroll a page to the very top, it waits for a second and then the top_bar is animated off. I scroll the page down, it waits for a second and then the top_bar is animated on.

I don't understand where this pause is coming from...
Please advise what am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/hc31qds5/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use CSS3 transitions for the most responsive effect. Try this:

CSS

```
.top_bar {
    max-height: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    background:#156373;
    color: #fff;
    text-align:center;
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}
.top_bar.sticky {
    max-height: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}
```

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.top_bar').addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $('.top_bar').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/hc31qds5/2/)

#### UPDATE

Here it is with jquery animate without the delay:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.top_bar').stop().animate({
            "margin-top": 0
        }, 200);
    } else {
        $('.top_bar').stop().animate({
            "margin-top": -70
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/hc31qds5/4/)

You just needed to make sure to `stop()` the previous animation.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I need to support IE8-9. And also it doesn't matter if I animate height or margin-top, the pause is still there... As I wrote in my question I want to animate margin because it looks better.

Comment: Thanks, that works exactly as I wanted. However there's really some performance issue like you said. It works slowly in FireFox, but it's fast and smooth in Chrome and IE11.

Comment: Feel free to select as correct answer if you're satisfied =P